# Can a NGINX proxy server pass requests to (server A) after finishing a job on (server B)?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

Currently, clients are uploading data to the old web server, but we want the clients to start uploading data to the new server.

However, we want current uploads to the old server to be continued, while new uploads are passed the new server.

After all uploads to the old servers are completed, we expect all new requests to go to the new server.

I was wondering if this is possible to accomplish with a NGINX proxy?

The proxy also should be able to handle web sockets.

Possible ideas:

1. A command (or function) that will switch proxied servers, without restarting the proxy and is specific to a connection.
2. A condition in the config that will tell the proxy to pass requests to a new server after a job is completed on the old server.

Answer (score 0):

This should pretty much "just work" with nginx using upstreams and, optionally, nginx reloads. I'm not sure what you mean by "specific to a connection" in this context, but making some assumptions about your setup...

Assuming the upload point application will be called "uploadpoint" and that initially it is going to `point1` and that `point2` is what you want to move it to:

```
upstream uploadpoint {
    server point1.example.com;
    server point2.example.com backup;
}
```

(For additional parameters relating to health checks, etc check the official [upstream documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)). 
Then within your server block you would point at that location:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name public.example.com;

   location /upload {
      proxy_pass http://uploadpoint/doupload/;
   }
}
```

In this case, you have an upstream which prefers to go to 'point1', but once it is down, everything will automatically begin going to `point2`. At some point you can switch the primary and `backup` (or even remove the old one depending on if you want to have a secondary) and issue a `service nginx reload` or `kill -HUP <nginx_pid>`. *In your case, this is likely what you would do to get a graceful switch rather than bringing down `point`1 and having it failover*.

```
upstream uploadpoint {
    server point2.example.com;
    server point1.example.com backup;
}
```

When nginx reloads, it allows the connections to drain (which I believe is what you're asking) for anything existing before sending new things over.

You will also want to review the various options around `proxy_pass`, especially `[proxy_next_upstream][2]`.